# Cocompletion and functor categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

If C is a locally small category, then is there an isomorphism of categories $[C:Sets]^{op} \cong [C^{op}:Sets]$?

I feel that there should be since they are both in some sense "spanned" by the re presentable functors $Hom_C(-,c)$ and $Hom_C(c,-)$ respectivly.

Comment: In general, $[A,B]^{op} \cong [A^{op},B^{op}]$.

Comment: @rafaelm are you sure? Because $[A^{op},B^{op}]\cong [A,B]$ and thus would follow $[A,B]^{op}\cong[A,B]$. Is this so?

Comment: If we have functor $F \colon A \to B$, then we have functor $F^{op} \colon A^{op} \to B^{op}$ given with the same action as $F$. But if we have natural transformation $\alpha \colon F \to G$ in $[A,B]$, then the corresponding natural transformation in $[A^{op},B^{op}]$ goes in the opposite direction: $\alpha^{op} \colon G^{op} \to F^{op}$.

Comment: Just write down the definition  of natural transformation and of opposite category. :)

Comment: So, your claim $[A^{op},B^{op}] \cong [A,B]$ is false in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider the case $C=1$ for example (the general case being similar). $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is not equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}$ since in $\mathsf{Set}$ the functor $X \times -$ preserves colimits for each $X$, but of course the dual statement, that $X \sqcup - $ preserves products, is not true. Or even more simply, in $\mathsf{Set}$ we have that every morphism to the initial object is an isomorphism, but the dual statement, that every morphism from the terminal object is an isomorphism, is far from being true.

Comment: Hmmm... but their would at least be an adjunction though? or does this fail since C is not small,
Since, the local smallness of C implies it is Sets enriched and Sets satisfies all the requirements to use Isbell duality.... (I have no experience with coends.. so the proof is difficult to go through)

Comment: The proof of what? Your comment is very confusing ...

Comment: Sorry haha, the proof of Isbell duality is hard for me to follow since I've never worked with coends before...

I as wondering if, given the assumptions on C, if a version of Isbell duality could be used to obtain adjoint functors between [C^{op}:Sets] and [C: Sets]^{op} even though C is not small itself.

Comment: No. You need to restrict to a suitable subcategory on both sides in order to get the relevant universal properties.